# python fails to execute a windows command with find

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess, call

I want to execute the command:

```
dir c: | find "File"
```

for the number of the files in a folder.

Neithor

```
subprocess.call(['dir c: | find "File"'], shell=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['dir', 'c:', '| find "File"'], shell=True)
```

works.

Python translated the command to

```
'"dir c: | find \"file\""'
```

caused the failure.

Is there any workaround for this?

Related note : http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2015/docs/python-3.4.2-docs-html/library/subprocess.html#notes

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `shell=True`, you're expected to pass command as a string, which is interpreted by shell (e.g. `cmd` on Windows) during execution. Passing arguments as list is applicable only when `shell=False`.

Try simply:

```
subprocess.call('dir c: | find "File"', shell=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with shell=false, it failed with error:                                                                                                                                                                             FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @69444091, but Łukasz told you to use `shell=True`, except with a string instead of a list. `subprocess.list2cmdline` doesn't know how to convert an argument list to a cmd shell command line. As to getting `FileNotFoundError`, `dir` is a built-in command in the cmd shell. Use the `where.exe` command to determine whether a command is an external executable (e.g. `xcopy.exe`) or built into the shell (e.g. `copy`).

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, I failed to find 'dir' command from windows, so I can't execute the command with 'shell=False'.
But it works with

```
os.chdir('C:')
cdirszbuf = os.popen('dir | find "File"')
cdirinfo = cdirszbuf.readlines()
```

Thanks

Comment: In Python 3 `os.popen` just calls `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` and wraps the result in a file-like class. Also, AFAIK, no one ever told you to use `shell=False`, and I already explained that `dir` is a built-in shell command. There is no `dir.exe` to execute. You have to use the shell for this and to support command-line syntax such as `'|'` for creating a pipe between two commands.